# Webpack and external libraries with dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dependencies

I am building small small React(webpack) chat app. I am using VoiceLayer as backend for my chat app. It provides [web SDK](https://developers.voicelayer.io/docs/main/javascript/index.html), but problem is that i do not have access to SDK source, just pre-built js files, so cant install it like other modules 'npm i voicelayer'. SDK contains 5 file, one main voiclayer.js with 4 js dependencies. I add loader like this in webpack conf:

```
  {
    test: resolve('./src/utils/voicelayersdk/voicelayer.js'),
    loader: "imports?this=>window",
  },
  {
    test: resolve('./src/utils/voicelayersdk/voicelayer.js'),
    loader: "exports?VoiceLayer",
  },
```

and i can import it like this:

```
const VoiceLayer = require('../utils/voicelayersdk/voicelayer.js');
```

but vicelayer.js still needs other 4 dependencies, and i see error in     console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://127.0.0.1:9000/ew.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://127.0.0.1:9000/rw.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://127.0.0.1:9000/dw.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

So how do I import all of them in a way it will work, I tried import all of them like `require('../utils/voicelayersdk/sw.js')....;` but no luck.

Also when initializing VoiceLayer object i can set working directory

```
const voicelayer = new VoiceLayer(appKey, appSecret, {
  directory: '../utils/voicelayersdk',
});
```

but still i need to include them somehow, path does not exists after build.

Answer (score 0):

From the Voicelayer documentation:

> Since the workers are automatically imported into when you import voicelayer.js the only step required to get started with the SDK is:`<script src="voicelayer.js"></script>;`

Once you have included the script in one of your HTML files, the other dependencies should be loaded automatically, provided they are in the same folder.

Comment: It is a Node app, think it is little bit more complicated than that :-)

Comment: The official doc is pretty clear about the install. Not sure why being a Node.js app would make it any more complicated.
https://developers.voicelayer.io/docs/main/javascript/sdk.html

Comment: still not following you, there is only one HTML file index, i cannot import it like on regular web page in that  index html, i would not be able to use in any of my js modules (new VoiceLayer would be undefined).Why there are node modules, and webpack loaders if i could add script just like in regular web page and use it. Anyway any path that i put for src int that <script> would not work ,since webpack bundles it to singe js file

Answer (score 0):

guys from VoiceLayer responded :-), so anyone who has problems with pre-built scripts with dependencies, they can be included in webpack with

```
copy-webpack-plugin
```

> I have created an application using webpack and had a similar issue.
>   If you are not using webpack please let me know what you are using and
>   I can investigate. If you are using webpack then try the following:
>   Put the files in `vendor` then use the following in the webpack
>   configuration.
>
> Install the `copy-webpack-plugin` with: npm install --save-dev
>   copy-webpack-plugin In the webpack config add:

```
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
//...
plugins: [
    // ...
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'vendor', to: 'scripts/voicelayer' }
    ])
  ],
```